# I need to create 2 color Curve Responsive background with SVG

Tags: css, svg, background, responsive

I need to create curve Responsive SVG background, with two color.

[image: 1]

i Tried this below code:

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" width="100%" height="100%" viewBox="0 0 100% 100%" class="hidden-xs hidden-sm">
                        <defs>
                            <clipPath id="clip-Nye">
                                <rect width="100%" height="100%"/>
                            </clipPath>
                        </defs>
                        <g id="Nye" data-name="Nye" clip-path="url(#clip-Nye)">
                            <rect width="100%" height="100%" fill="#fff"/>
                            <path id="Rectangle" d="M0,453.226,817.641,0s696,663.078,406.715,730.84q-335.194,78.515-815.961,459.149C142.369,1400.607,0,453.226,0,453.226Z" transform="matrix(-0.485, 0.875, -0.875, -0.485, 1914.704, 197.622)" fill="#01b0f0"/>
                        </g>
                    </svg>
```

The Issue is that, when i minimize page with CTRL + -, SVG not show properly and side show blank.

what i do wrong? any idea?

Comment: There is no such thing as `viewBox="0 0 100% 100%"` One solution would be using `style="width:100vw; height:100vh"` and `preserveAspectRatio="none"`. In your case the `viewBox` should be something like `viewBox="0 0 1300 1220"`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try the use of [`radial-gradient`](https://drafts.csswg.org/css-images-3/#radial-gradients):

```css
body {
  margin:0;
  height:100vh;
  background:radial-gradient(100% 200% at left,white 50%,#01b0f0 50.1%);
}
```

Comment: Thanks Temani Afif, I use your idea, but the problem is that, in large height curve show in blur, which not look ok. Any idea?

Comment: @user3679450 check the update .. replaced 50.5 by 50.1

Comment: @user3679450 good, don't forget to accept the answer if it solves your issue ;)